# Prove this polynomial only has one simple positive root

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have the following polynomial
$$p(x)=-x^n+A_1x^{n-1}+\ldots +A_{n-1}x+A_n$$
where $A_1=a_1$, $A_2=a_2b_1$, $A_3=a_3b_2b_1$, $\ldots$, $A_n=a_nb_{n-1}\ldots b_2b_1$ with $b_i>0, a_i \geq 0$. I have to prove that it has only one simple positive root. I am suggested to use
$$p(x)=x^n(q(x)-1)$$
with $q(x)\in k[x,x^{-1}]$.

I know that it has only one positive root because of Descartes' rule of signs, but I don't know how to prove it is simple. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: *Maybe* the fact that a multiple zero is a common zero of $p(x)$ and its derivative could be used. [I haven't tried that...]

Comment: I'm sure that you mean $p(x) = x^{n-1}(q(x)-1)$. As each polynomial of degree $n$ has exactly $n$ zeros (counting multiplicities) and you already have the common zero $x_0=0$ with multiplicity $n-1$, just one zero is missing (if you would have $n$ as exponent there would be more than $n$ zeros which is impossible). Therefore the last zero comes from $q(x)-1=0$ and is simple, so that the total number of zeros is $(n-1) + 1 = n$.

Comment: Unimportant quibble about language: If $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)^2$ it is true that $p$ "only has one simple positive root".

Comment: What does "simple" mean?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta $a$ is a simple root of $f$ if $f(a)=0$ but $f'(a)\ne0$. (If $f$ is a polynomial this says just that $x-a$ divides $f$ and $(x-a)^2$ does not.)

Comment: @LegNaiB I get why you are confused, but it is $p(x)=x^n(q(x)-1)$. This is not a factorization as such, and doesn't mean that $0$ is a root. Here, $q(x)=A_1x^{-1}+\ldots +A_{n-1}x^{-n+1}+A_nx^{-n}$ (note that this is not defined for $x=0$, that's why it isn't a root)

Comment: @kubo Thanks for the clarification. I felt free to add this to the question as it wasn't clear for me.

Comment: Descartes rule of signs counts roots with multiplicity. Hence one sign change means one positive root which is not a multiple root.

Comment: What is the purpose of the $a_i$ and $b_i$? Each sequence of $A_i \ge 0$ can be written in the form $A_i = a_ib_{i-1}...b_1$.